# Parallel loading when installing Plotly package

Tags: r, parallel-processing, plotly

I am using R studio Version 0.99.760, with R 3.2.2. I am trying to install "plotly" package and other ones from CRAN, when the query is being processed it comes to the point of "loading required package parallel" and leaves the installation with "installation of package ‘plotly’ had non-zero exit status".  This also happens when trying to install markdown package. I have the package parallel installed and loaded though ?? any idea how to overcome this ?

Comment: Please share more explicit error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly")
Downloading github repo ropensci/plotly@master
Installing plotly
Skipping 1 packages not available: viridis
Skipping 4 packages ahead of CRAN: curl, htmlwidgets, R6, Rcpp
"C:/PROGRA~1/RRO/R-32~1.1/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/Navin/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpkX8wjW/devtools18387fd916b0/ropensci-plotly-01e8c61" --library="C:/Users/Navin/Documents/R/win-library/3.2"  \
--install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'plotly' ...
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** tests
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (plotly)
```